# Can you do SERS without a Raman microscope?

Tags: spectroscopy

Surface-enhanced Raman spectroscopy or surface-enhanced Raman scattering (SERS) is a surface-sensitive technique that enhances Raman scattering by molecules adsorbed on rough metal surfaces or by nanostructures such as plasmonic-magnetic silica nanotubes.

Does this require a Raman microscope? Remember you are not scanning on a large object or liquid in vials but molecules in the rough metal surfaces. If you just use a normal Raman spectrometer. Will it work on the SERS sample?

Comment: SERS is not a sample, it is a phenomenon in Raman spectroscopy. SERS does not need a Raman microscope. Any ordinary Raman spectrometer can be used to study SERS.

Comment: But SERS sample uses molecules that are absorbed in the rough metal surface. How can the laser reach this depth without the Raman microscope also focusing down the laser to the very smaller nanometer scale?

Comment: I used to teach SERS on an educational Raman spectrometer with an integration time of 1 min (Au nanoparticles). You do not need an extra-powerful laser or a Raman microscope.

Comment: I only have a 532nm Raman spectrometer. I plan to buy an Au SERS substrate. Should I also buy a sample stage? what I have are only attachments in front like this https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/4927/5D1GEw.jpg

Comment: We never used a sample stage and I am not familiar with your Raman spectrometer. What is your analyte to begin with?

Comment: Just water for a start. How do you put the slide of glass in front of the horizontal Raman device? You just tape it?

Comment: It was not horizontal. The configuration was such that the beam would hit the surface vertically, so you could put the sample on the sample. Water will **not** show SERS effect.

Comment: so need to use this vertical sample holder to use SERS? https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/3048/cRWs7K.jpg  can't horizontal position work? what other substance in house can show SERS effect when used with a silver substrate? I just want to learn about SERS.,

Comment: First study the theory of SERS. If you wish to spend money, this vertical stand would work. Just curious, if this is a home research project or an academic one?

Comment: A home research project. If I won't buy the vertical stand. Horizonal setup can work if I know where is the focal point and just taping the glass slide to the front, isn't it?

Comment: SERS does not care about the orientation of the sample.

Comment: ok. last question. What cells or tissues in the human body will show SERS effect using 532nm Raman? I know colored ones can't be used because of fluorescence. But SERS is supposed to overcome fluorescence. So can red blood be used as analyte? or red tissues?

Comment: No experience in this domain.

Comment: Indeed study spectroscopy in general first. Because I think it is not the best to discuss (here) polymers identitification, sers, fluorescence microscopy without knowing same basic first. This said, congratulations on the experimental part. Your spectra look great.

Comment: Btw Farooq. Why wont water show any SERS effect? I read it can detect contaminants in water in one part of millions. One reason id buy expensive SERS substrate is to study contaminants of water. Tnx